# First cohomology of tangent sheaf of rational curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $C$ be a reduced, connected, projective and purely one-dimensional scheme of finite type over a field $k$.
Suppose that $C$ is rational, i.e. that the normalisation of $C$ is a disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.
Let $T_C = \mathcal{H}om(\Omega^1_C,\mathcal{O}_C)$ be the tangent sheaf of $C$.

**Question:** Is it true that $H^1(C,T_C)$ vanishes?

You may additionally assume that $C$ has only planar singularities, but I'm not sure this is needed.
The question is true if $C$ is smooth.
For context, a positive answer would imply that $C$ has no locally trivial deformations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $C$ be the union of 5 lines in general position in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (hence with 10 pairwise intersection points $P_{ij}$, $1 \le i < j \le 5$) and let $F$ be the equation of $C$. We have the standard exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_C(-5) \stackrel{dF}\to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}\vert_C \to \Omega_C \to 0.
$$
Taking its dual we obtain an exact sequence
$$
0 \to T_C \to T_{\mathbb{P}^2}\vert_C \stackrel{dF}\to \mathcal{O}_C(5) \to \bigoplus_{1 \le i < j \le 5} \mathcal{O}_{P_{ij}} \to 0.
$$
Now an easy computation of Euler characteristics gives
$$
\chi(T_{\mathbb{P}^2}\vert_C) = 5,
\quad
\chi(\mathcal{O}_C(5)) = 20,
\quad 
\chi(\mathcal{O}_{P_{ij}}) = 1,
$$
hence $\chi(T_C) = 5 - 20 + 10 = -5$, and since $C$ is 1-dimensional, it follows that $H^1(C,T_C)$ is non-zero.

Comment: Doesn't the exactness on the left of the first sequence require the smoothness of $C$?

Comment: @Jef: no. $dF$ is generically injective so its kernel is torsion, hence zero since $\mathscr{O}_C(-5)$ is torsion free.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer!